# How to set up eloquent relationships to query table where relationship between two tables exists in a third table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.7 and mysql. I need help setting up my eloquent relationships between 3 tables.

Locations

```
id
city
state
```

Services

```
id
name
```

Allowed_Locations

```
location_id (id from Locations table)
service_id (id from Services table)
```

Locations

```
id, city, state
1, San Diego, California
2, Seattle, Washington 
3, Portland, Oregon
```

Services

```
id, name 
1, Tax Services
2, Legal Services
```

Allowed Locations

```
location_id, service_id
1, 1
1, 2
3, 2
```

Basically one service can be available in many locations. I want to be able to query services, along with the locations the service is available in

Heres an example of what I am looking to return. I know how to do this using MySQL but I'm not sure how to set up eloquent relationships

```
{
    {
        id: 1,
        name: Tax Services
        locations: 
        {
            {
                id: 1,
                city: San Diego,
                state: California,
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                city: Seattle,
                state: Washington,
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                city: Seattle,
                state: Washington,
            },
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: Legal Services
        locations: 
        {
            {
                id: 3,
                city: Portland,
                state: Oregon,
            },
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out

```
public function locations() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Locations', 'allowed_locations', 'service_id','location_id');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this also
In *Service* Model,

```
public function locations() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Locations', 'allowed_locations');
}
```

You need to pass 'service_id' as third and 'location_id' as forth arguments if you have different primary key in **Services** and **Locations** table.

Answer (score 0):

there is many to many relationship between location and service so you just need to read Laravel's many to many relation section and add some functions to your models also migration for your pivot table.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Hi Amin Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would suggest including some code examples in your answer. This answer would have a lot of value if the code examples used the schema that the OP has already detailed. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

make this relationship in your service eloquent

```
public function locations() {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Location', 'allowed_locations', 
         'service_id','location_id');
       }
```

and in controller use this query to get all services with multiple location

```
$services = Service::with('locations')->get();
```